# Custom permission and description attribute of custom permission

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I tried to add custom permission in an android application, but all my suggestions for "description" attribute were wrong. How can I add it?

Manifest declaration:

```
<permission android:protectionLevel="dangerous"
     android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
     android:description="This is adangerous app" />
```

Error:

> String type not allowed

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of what you have tried that doesn't work, along with the exact error message?

Comment: Eclipse, at least, seems to want the description to be a string resource, IIRC.

Comment: @Tanis.7x  <permission android:protectionLevel="dangerous" android:name="course.labs.permissions.DANGEROUS_ACTIVITY_PERM"
    android:description="This is adangerous app" />

Comment: error message "string type not allowed"

Comment: @CommonsWare  How can i add a string resource

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

Comment: Note that the type requirement of the manifest attribute tag is independent of your IDE; the error is returned from AAPT.

Answer (score 2):

Your `android:description` attribute *must* be a reference to a String resource (e.g. `@string/my_description_string`).

From the [`<permission>` tag docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html):

> *android:description*
>
> A user-readable description of the permission, longer and more informative than the label. It may be displayed to explain the permission to the user — for example, when the user is asked whether to grant the permission to another application.
>
> This attribute must be set as a reference to a string resource; unlike the label attribute, it cannot be a raw string.